# How to run a video in vlc player in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0

We are developing a website which needs to play videos. How to run a video in vlc player in silverlight

Comment: You want to run a program from a website or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yes want to run from a website. If not vlc suggest any good control with maximum file type support including avi; further I need support for SWF as well

Comment: I m not a web develloper, but that would mean that anybody wanting to play a video on your website must have VLC installed, isn t a embedded player a better solution?

Comment: We want it to go through silverlight. Could you spread some more light on embed?

Comment: Like I said, I never used silverlight, and never gone far in html/php, but I was thinking about youtube-like video player. Thinking about it, you still need to have flash installed, so it don t solve the problem.

Comment: Suggest any other control which is compatible with silverlight